# Two Raspberry Pi on one router

Tags: networking

I have the following:

- A router with external ip address 209.xx.xx.xx.
  This router forwards to the ip address of the first rpi (rpi#1) (ports 80 and 443 to 192.168.1.170) and a random port (1234) to the second pi (rpi#2).
- A domain name from noip.com forwards to rpi#1 via 209.xx.xx.xx.
  I added SSL (letsencrypt) to rpi#1. This is now secure (http -> https).
- I have a second rpi (rpi#2) on 192.168.1.139 on the same router. The router forwards a port (1234) to rpi#2. This is not secure (http).

This is all working fine.

Now:
I would like to add SSL to rpi#2.
However, since noip.com can only forward to one external ip address, I can then not add SSL to rpi#2.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You write "*a domain name forwards to rpi#1 via 209.xx.xx.xx*". That cannot be done with a domain name. You mean "a domain name is mapped to ip address 209.xx.xx.xx", isn't it?

Comment: This is not a problem of Raspberry Pi. It is a problem to configure your router with port forwarding. The destination ip 209.xx.xx.xx to ports 80 and 443 must be forwarded to rpi#1 and the destination ip 209.xx.xx.xx to port 1234 must be forwarded to rpi#2. This are two forwarding rules. The protocol http or https has nothing to do with port forwarding. The external program uses https and the server program on a RasPi must understand it. You should better ask at https://superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks Ingo!
Comment 1: yes, you are correct. Sorry, could not explain better...
Comment 2: Again you are right. It's not a rpi problem. Just wondered if anyone had the same set up and found a way to make it work.

Comment: Take a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html I've got one Raspberry Pi with an internet facing webserver. I've another one running FlightAware (which includes a webserver). I've got `ProxyPass /data http://faware.local:8080/data` and `ProxyPassReverse /data http://faware.local:8080/data` [plus a few more] statements in the internet webserver to allow me to access my FlightAware system from the public internet.